# What constraints does a Wrap pass to its children?

Tags: flutter, constraints

flutter: What constraint a Wrap passes to its children?

Inside a scrollView:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Wrap(
     direction: Axis.vertical,
     children: [child1, child2, child3]
   )
)
```

outside ScrollView:

```
   Container(  
      child: Wrap(
         direction: Axis.vertical,
         children: [child1, child2, child3]
       )
   )
```

For Column/Row, it passes infinite constraint for its children in main axis. How about Wrap?

Comment: wrap also gives infinitive constraints but when over flowed child would be transfered to next row or column. I think what you are looking can be solved by setting mainAxisSize property of column or row.

Comment: wrap `child1` (or any other child) with `LayoutBuilder` and add `print(constraints)` inside `builder` callback

Comment: From widget inspector, a Wrap gives its children unconstrained in both width and height.